# Selenium WebDriver and HTML Window location by using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver in conjunction with java.awt.Robot to better simulate user interaction with our web application. Yes, I know it's probably unnecessary, but the customers I serve demand it.

Currently things are working pretty well, however I have a minor snag in that I can't seem to find a good way to get the web elements' on screen position. Things like the title bar, menu bar, navigation bar, etc all push the content down on the physical screen (which Robot gets its coordinates from), but has no impact on where Selenium reports the element is.

When I call: `element.getLocation();` on a Selenium WebElement, it always gives me its location relative to the HTML content render pane, not the browser window itself.

A better illustration is: `driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getLocation();` always returns 0,0, regardless of the window's actual on-screen location.

Right now I am hacking it by adding a vertical and horizontal offset after maximizing the window, but these aren't the same between different browsers (IE's top decorations take up more room then Firefox's, for example), and may be different for each user if they have bookmark tool bars, search bars, etc added in.

Yes, I know I could run in full screen mode, but I'd rather not, if at all possible.

Is there a way to use WebDriver to get the physical on-screen location of elements in a reliable manner?

Comment: You might be interested in starring this issue to express interest to the Selenium team: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5267

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe there's no way to get the real on-screen location of the elements on the page.

I also think the fullscreen mode is your best bet.

That said, I wrote a `RobotCalibration` class that can detect the real offsets of your current browser. It opens a specially crafted page and uses the `Robot` class to click on it. The algorithm starts in the center of the browser and then uses bisecting to find the top left corner of the browser viewport.

Tested on IE8 and FF18. Works for both maximized and windowed browsers. Known issue: If you have a top Bookmarks Toolbar enabled, it may click on some of the bookmarks and therefore redirect. It can be handled pretty easily, but I left it up to you if you needed that :).

The testing page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" onclick="document.getElementById('counter').value++">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Calibration Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img height="1" width="1" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;"
        onclick="document.getElementById('done').value = 'yep'" />
    <input type="text" id="counter" value="0" />
    <input type="text" id="done" value="nope" />
</body>
</html>
```

The `RobotCalibration` class. It's a little bit long, so I suggest you to copypaste it into your favourite IDE and explore it there:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class RobotCalibration {

    public static Point calibrate(WebDriver driver) {
        return new RobotCalibration(driver).calibrate();
    }

    /** Time for which to wait for the page response. */
    private static final long TIMEOUT = 1000;

    private final WebDriver driver;
    private final Robot r;

    private final Point browserCenter;
    private int leftX;
    private int rightX;
    private int midX;
    private int topY;
    private int bottomY;
    private int midY;

    private RobotCalibration(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        try {
            driver.manage().window().getSize();
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException headlessBrowserException) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Calibrating a headless browser makes no sense.", headlessBrowserException);
        }

        try {
            this.r = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException headlessEnvironmentException) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Robot won't work on headless environments.", headlessEnvironmentException);
        }

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        org.openqa.selenium.Dimension browserSize = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        org.openqa.selenium.Point browserPos = driver.manage().window().getPosition();

        // a maximized browser returns negative position
        // a maximized browser returns size larger than actual screen size
        // you can't click outside the screen
        leftX = Math.max(0, browserPos.x);
        rightX = Math.min(leftX + browserSize.width, screenSize.width - 1);
        midX = (leftX + rightX) /2;

        topY = Math.max(0, browserPos.y);
        bottomY = Math.min(topY + browserSize.height, screenSize.height - 1);
        midY = (topY + bottomY) /2;

        browserCenter = new Point(midX, midY);
    }

    private Point calibrate() {
        driver.get(Paths.get("files/RobotCalibration.html").toUri().toString());

        // find left border
        while (leftX < rightX) {
            click(midX, midY);
            if (clickWasSuccessful()) {
                rightX = midX;
            } else {
                leftX = midX + 1;
                // close any menu we could have opened
                click(browserCenter.x, browserCenter.y);
            }
            midX = (leftX + rightX) /2;
        }

        // find top border
        while (topY < bottomY) {
            click(midX, midY);
            if (clickWasSuccessful()) {
                bottomY = midY;
            } else {
                topY = midY + 1;
                // close any menu we could have opened
                click(browserCenter.x, browserCenter.y);
            }
            midY = (topY + bottomY) /2;
        }

        if (!isCalibrated()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't calibrate the Robot.");
        }
        return new Point(midX, midY);
    }

    /** clicks on the specified location */
    private void click(int x, int y) {
        r.mouseMove(x, y);
        r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

        // for some reason, my IE8 can't properly register clicks that are close
        // to each other faster than click every half a second
        if (driver instanceof InternetExplorerDriver) {
            sleep(500);
        }
    }

    private static void sleep(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            // nothing to do
        }
    }

    private int counter = 0;
    /** @return whether the click on a page was successful */
    private boolean clickWasSuccessful() {
        counter++;

        long targetTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + TIMEOUT;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < targetTime) {
            int pageCounter = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.id("counter")).getAttribute("value"));
            if (counter == pageCounter) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /** @return whether the top left corner has already been clicked at */
    private boolean isCalibrated() {
        long targetTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + TIMEOUT;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < targetTime) {
            if (driver.findElement(By.id("done")).getAttribute("value").equals("yep")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Sample usage:

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
Point p = RobotCalibration.calibrate(driver);
System.out.println("Left offset: " + p.x + ", top offset: " + p.y);
driver.quit();
```

Feel free to ask any questions if something is unclear.

Comment: I was actually going to do the exact same thing, just hoping for a more elegant solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @Merkidemis Yeah, I tried for some time to find a solution, because I needed it, too. Ended up with the fullscreen mode which only annoys me because of [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4067) which makes screenshots taken at fullscreen unusable.

Comment: I'm going to have to save these various offsets, as the web app I am testing will open new windows without an address bar, for example.  The calibration done at the start of the session (with address and menu bars) would be useless.

Comment: Great answer. I wish I could give more than one upvote. If you're inside a frame, then you will need to calibrate to the location of the iframe too.

Comment: @Merkidemis Well, you could run it at every new browser window opened (after a `switchTo()` method call), but it's true that those values won't change too much across different sessions. What about a middle way? Run calibration the first time and store the values locally in a file?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like selenium has a way to get the element position relative to your browser window now. In one of my tests I was trying to verify that a page was anchored to a certain position and figured the best way to do this was to get an element position relative to the window. This can be done using the **getCoordinates().inViewPort()** methods.

Here's some sample code to get a WebElement's relative location:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable;

public class RelativeElementLocation {

private static Point locationPoint;
private static Locatable elementLocation;
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement element;

public Point location() throws Throwable {
    driver.get("Insert your URL here");
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("Insert id/css/xpath/ here"));
    elementLocation = (Locatable) element;
    locationPoint = elementLocation.getCoordinates().inViewPort();
    System.out.println(locationPoint);

    return locationPoint; 
    }
}
```

The only caveat to the **inViewPort()** method is that if you try to get the relative element location of an element that currently is not in page view, the method will scroll the page so that the element is in view and then give you the relative position. Meaning, say if you try to get an element's relative position that is above your browser page view, it's not going to give you a negative y coordinate, but rather scroll up to that element and make the y coordinate zero.

Hope this helps, I'm new to Selenium and Java so if there are any mistakes in my code please forgive me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!!. I find this pretty accurate and convenient. I have verified that the coordinates given by Locatable are indeed the floor of the coordinates that getBoundingClientRect() gives using js on the page.

Answer (score 4):

There's a simpler way than [Slanec answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14677516/1192811) to get relative to absolute offset.

First you need a blank page with javascript [attached click listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/1192811) on window to get the coordinates and save them into a global variable :

```
window.coordinates = [];
window.attachEvent('click', function() {
     window.coordinates = [event.pageX, event.pageY];
});
```

Then you click and get relative click position through [`JavascriptExecutor`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) :

```
// browser center
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
Point point = driver.manage().window().getPosition()
    .translate(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

// Click through robot
click(point.x, point.y);
Thread.sleep(500);

// read coordinates
List<Object> coordinates = (List<Object>) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
    .executeScript("return window.coordinates;");
if (coordinates.size() != 2)
     throw new IllegalStateException("Javascript did not receive the click");

// point contains screen coordinates of upper left page point
point.translate(-((Integer)coordinates.get(0)),
                -((Integer)coordinates.get(1)));
```

Comment: This is so good and I'm so ashamed I didn't come up with it myself! Nice.

Answer (score 0):

The current Selenium doesn't implement the API to get the absolute location of web element. But the [SAFS](http://safsdev.sourceforge.net/Default.htm) has implemented one version to get the absolute location of web element.

The thinking is below:

1. Get the element's location **relative** to the frame. Because there may be lots of frames in one browser web page. Also, the frame may be implanted in another frame. So, it's better to use a class with parent frame to recursively search to the outer most frame location.

`

```
class FrameElement {
    FrameElement parent;
    Point location;

    FrameElement(FrameElement parent, WebElement frame) throws ... {
        if(parent != null) {
            this.parent = parent;
            location = frame.getLocation().moveBy(parent.getLocation().x, parent.getLocation().y);
        } else {
            location = frame.getLocation();
        }
    }

    public Point getLocation() {return location;} 
}

Point p = webelement.getLocation();
```

2. Add frame's location, relative to browser client area(the part exclude toolbar, menu, etc.).
3. Add the browser client area, relative to browser window.
4. Add the browser window's location, relative to screen.