# Java selenium. disable auto scrolling of the page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I'm using selenium of Java for automation tests and the browser is Firefox.

This is my sample code:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/a"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
Actions action2 = action.moveToElement(elem);
action2.perform();
```

The problem is that "moveToElement" action is triggering auto scrolling event of the page.
I want the page to remain as it was before without the scrolling.
somebody may know how can I disable this auto scrolling?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  WebDriver scrolls elements into view when acting on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable the autoscroll.

---

Some possible workarounds:

1. You could try to [fire a syntetic `mouseover` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911586/javascript-simulate-mouse-over-in-code) over your `WebElement` if that would help your cause.
2. After the `moveToElement()`, you could try rescroll to your needed position with [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scroll) or for example the <kbd>Page Up</kbd> key. This would, obviously, break the `mouseover` on the element, but maybe it's what you need.
3. You can position your real mouse cursor over the element via the [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. This might get a little tricky, you might need to enter the fullscreen mode with your browser (or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655581/selenium-and-html-window-location/14677516#14677516)) and then handle the scroll offsets manually, if there are some.

---

All depends on your intentions, on what you really need to do with the element and why.