# Using .getLocations to determine element movement against two browsers

Tags: java, python, selenium, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

My company is trying to perform a browser update from IE8 to IE11. They want my team to automate tests that determine if their applications' web-elements have shifted at all in IE11 compared to IE8.

I did some [research](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getLocation()) and found that the `.getLocation()` method returns the `(x,y)` points of an element on the screen. My questions are: what do they use exactly to measure x and y coordinates (i.e. pixels / screen size)? Does it take into account the browser's tool bar at the top of the screen?

I have my doubts about the `.getLocation()`method so is there a better and more efficient way (than `.getLocation()`) of determining if a shift has occurred in a web-element's location from browser to browser?

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655581/selenium-webdriver-and-html-window-location-by-using-java), it looks like the location is measured from the HTML content render pane and therefore ignores the browser window, etc.

You could use [`JavascriptExecutor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) and then [`.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) but I'm not sure if that will return you any different results. My guess is `.getLocation` is a wrapper to the JS commands but I can't prove that.

You might consider using an existing tool that compares a page in two browsers. I remember using one years ago that displayed every difference in element position between two browsers but I don't remember now what it was.

Comment: thank you. I've been researching and it might be what I am looking for; a .getLocation() with more functionality. Can this be implemented using the [JavascriptExecutor](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)?

Comment: It can but I'm not sure what additional functionality it would get you. From what I can gather, you should be able to accomplish your objective using just `.getLocation()`. I would be shocked if this wasn't already created... I would do more searching for existing tools.